# Google SSO: Sign Out Error (Website)

Tags: javascript, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

We are trying to auto sign out from google when you open the logout.php.
Sometime it works but mostly we got the error nb.
Does anyone know how to fix the issue ?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script>
           setTimeout(function() {
                var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                    window.location.href='NEWPAGE.php' ?>';
                });
            }, 500);
    </script>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: nb
    at tE (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.R4vvmD-bxFg.O/m=signin2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=/cb=gapi.loaded_0:183:39)
    at jF.<anonymous> (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.R4vvmD-bxFg.O/m=signin2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=/cb=gapi.loaded_0:224:235)
    at new _.C (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.R4vvmD-bxFg.O/m=signin2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=/cb=gapi.loaded_0:112:296)
    at jF.BT (https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_GB.R4vvmD-bxFg.O/m=signin2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=/cb=gapi.loaded_0:224:215)
    at signOut (1:220:42)
    at 1:216:17
    at https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js:18:348
    at Oa (https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js:10:467)
    at b (https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js:18:331)
    at Array.E.(anonymous function) (https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js:18:427)
```

Comment: why is this code inside setTimeout function?

Comment: @Luke there should be a short time with a loading spinner

Comment: @Lennart what's the purpose of wasting your user's time like that (albeit only half a second, but still)? Why do you need to delay the signout operation? What do you gain from that?

Comment: Do you think this causes the error ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could mess things up I guess. Why not remove it and see, since it's essentially pointless anyway.

Comment: @ADyson Meanwhile I removed it and nothing happened...same issue.

Comment: I think Google has major problems with this API service.  I've got my setup almost working, but i've had to hack the holy hell out of it.

Comment: @indospace.io Would you mind providing an answer or link to a working implementation or description of a fix if you're able to?

Answer (score 0):

*Google+ Sign-in feature is fully deprecated and is being shut down on March 7, 2019. This will be a progressive shutdown, with intermittent failures starting as early as January 28, 2019.*

You must use this now: https://developers.google.com/identity/